# Android - ListView in notification content view

Tags: android, listview, notifications

Can I put a ListView in a notification's content view? If so, how can I do it?

In another app, I have a ListView inside a widget, using RemoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(), RemoteViewsService and RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory, which is working.

I've tried doing the same thing for a notification, but it doesn't work. The app doesn't crash, there's no error in the log but the ListView isn't showing. The RemoteViewsService isn't even called.

Creating the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.lvNotificationList, new Intent(this, ListService.class));

builder
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentTitle("Test")
        .setContent(views)
        .setCustomBigContentView(views)
        .setCustomHeadsUpContentView(views)
        .setCustomContentView(views);
Notification not = builder.build();
```

Notification layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My list should appear below this" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvNotificationList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

ListService:

```
public class ListService extends RemoteViewsService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyTag";

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onGetViewFactory()");
        return new ListProvider(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

Declaration of ListService in manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".ListService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
```

ListProvider:

```
public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory  {
    private static final String TAG = "MyTag";

    private Context context;

    public ListProvider(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ListProvider.getViewAt(), position=" + position);

        RemoteViews ret = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.row_notification_list);
        ...
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
    }
}
```

The TextView above the ListView is shown but the list remains empty...

Comment: found any solution over it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I should have RTFM... from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html:

void setRemoteAdapter (int viewId, Intent intent)

Equivalent to calling setRemoteViewsAdapter(Intent). **Can only be used for App Widgets.**

So I guess the answer to my question "Can I put a ListView in a notification's content view" is *no*...

Comment: But is this really just impossible? any ideas?

Comment: Create a separate ListView Adapter which duplicates the functionality of the `RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory` - Yeah ... I know.

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically possible to add a `ListView` in a notification row since `ListView` is annotated by @RemoteView. See line 148 of the `ListView` source code is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java).

*However, after inflating the `ListView`, it **CANNOT** be scrolled vertically since the gesture is caught by the notification drawer for scrolling through all other the  notification set. Therefore, it is only theoretically possible but there is no practical use of adding a `ListView` into a notification view.

```
<ListView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/listView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="256dp"
  android:entries="@array/demo_string_array"
  android:background="@color/amber_dim"/>
```

Add a string-array at the res/values/string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <string-array name="demo_string_array">
    <item>Shuttle Badminton</item>
    <item>Tennis</item>
    <item>FootBall</item>
    <item>Basket Ball</item>
    <item>Table Tennis</item>
    <item>Chess</item>
    <item>Hockey</item>
</string-array>
```

[image]